# Benefits of formulating inverse problems,

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, research, inverse-problems

Why would an extensively researched direct problem be reformulated into an inverse problem?

Is it simply to create further research opportunities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are, of course, as many reasons as there are researchers.

- The inverse problem is, or might become, physically relevant (or relevant for other applications).
- The problem is more difficult or more general than previously tackled ones, so it will be interesting to know which techniques work and which do not.
- A researcher believes they can prove a result that is worth publication.
- Established results in a new setting is fertile ground for doctoral study, and the PhD student is likely to not have much competition there.